# Android get string from resource?

Tags: android, getstring

I want to get string from xml resource and put as string variable value this is my Code :

```java
String defaultText = Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.release_movie_message_now);
```

when run application system say error :

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>           Process: com.erlanggakmoekasan.imovie, PID: 26603
>           android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f0e0049
>               at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:363)
>               at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:456)
>               at com.erlanggakmoekasan.imovie.notifications.ReleaseTodayReceiver$1.onResponse(ReleaseTodayReceiver.java:68)
>               at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:83)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7073)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)

My `string.xml` is as following:

```xml
    <resources>
        <string name="release_movie_message_now">telah rilis sekarang, cek dan lihat!</string>
    </resources>
```

Any solution ?? note i'm doing in `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: `BroadcastReceiver` have context passed as argument in `#onRecieve()` . So you can use `context.getResources()` ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try with [**`getResources()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getResources())

> Returns a Resources instance for the application's package

```
String defaultText = getResources().getString(R.string.release_movie_message_now);
```

**FYI**

```
 getResources() is not recognize
```

Then you should add **`Context`** object before **getResources()**

Comment: before that i use getResources() but IDE say method getResources() is not recognize i'm doing in BroadcastReceiver

Comment: @Erlangga add `getApplicationContext().getResources()`

Comment: ok thats finis i add context befor getResources

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get string inside an activity/fragment then use below one

```
String message = getString(R.string.release_movie_message_now)
```

If you want it in broadcast receiver then

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   String message = context.getString(R.string.release_movie_message_now);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**In your Java File**

```
    String mytext = getResources().getString(R.string.mytextfromstringxmlfile);
```

**In your String.xml File**

```
    <string name="mytextfromstringxmlfile">Hello World</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

use getResources().getString(R.string.release_movie_message_now);
or if it's doesn't work, use context.getString(R.string.release_movie_message_now);